# invalid Regex group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create the following regex using Javascript.

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)([5-9]|[1-9]\d)
```

However, by doing this it gives me invalid group error in the console.

```
regExp = new RegExp("(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)([5-9]|[1-9]\d)", "gi");
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from exactly. I appreciate the help.

Thank you

EDIT: After some research I found that Javascript does not support lookbehinds.

So the error comes from `(?<!\\)`. 
Refer this newly asked question to find an alternative way to do the same job.
[How to check for odd numbers of backslashes in a regex using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334881/how-to-check-for-odd-numbers-of-backslashes-in-a-regex-using-javascript/50334980?noredirect=1#comment87690556_50334980)

Comment: Could you provide a string you're trying to validate the RegEx against?

Comment: You need to double-escape the `\ `.  You've escaped it once with `\\ `, so your regex reads: `(?<!\) `  This effectively escapes the `)`.

Comment: @FueledByCoffee any string that starts with an odd backslash following a number between 5 and 9 or double digits example 11.

Let's say    \9   or \11    or \\\5

Comment: @Amy Should it be like that you mean ?
new RegExp("(?<!\\\)(?:\\\{2})*\\\(?!\\\)([5-9]|[1-9]\d)", "gi");

Comment: @Ziko I am marking this as not-a-duplicate. Can I suggest that you remove your answer from the question, and answer the question yourself, instead?

Comment: @Anonymoose I can't post an answer on my post idk why..

Answer (score 4):

If your expression isn't dynamic, just use a literal:

```
var regExp = /(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)([5-9]|[1-9]\d)/gi;
```

The problem is that your escape sequences `\\` inside the string end up rendering `\` characters inside the regEx, which in turn end up escaping brackets they shouldn't, resulting in unterminated groups.

Comment: My expression is dynamic, taking an input binding using angular and validate it run time. However, this also gives me an error idk why, I tried it before asking the question tho

Comment: I mean if the regex itself is dynamic, e.g. `var regEx = new RegExp('[a-z]' + somePattern + '$');`, then you need to use the constructor, but otherwise you can just use a literal.

Comment: It is, I simplified it here to be clear but actually inside [5-9], I have something like "["+num_groups+"-9]" which is a number of groups captured in another input.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. In any case, the core of the issue is the escape sequences, check the answer linked by Wiktor.

Comment: I understand the escape thing in the question he provided but following it, it doesn't solve the problem and I'm still getting invalid group for this specific regex expression.

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from (?<!\\). It appears that javascript  do not support positive lookbehind assertions. If I remove it, everything works well. So it was not the escaping problem as mentioned above