# How to check for odd numbers of backslashes in a regex using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I have recently asked a question regarding an error I have been getting using a RegExp constructor in Javascript with lookbehind assertion.

What I want to do it, to check for a number input bigger than 5 preceded by an **odd** number of backslash, in other words, that is not preceded by an escaped backslash

Here is an example.

```
\5              // match !
\\5            // no match !
\\\5           // match!
```

The Regex I found online is

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\\(?!\\)([5-9]|[1-9]\d)
```

But the problem here is that `(?<!\\)` causes a problem with javascript throwing an error invalid regex group.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Finally, I know that my current regex also may have an error regarding the detection of a number larger than 5, for example \55 will not match. I would appreciate your help.

thank you

Comment: You can use capturing groups to further control the output: `/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)\\([5-9]|[1-9]\d+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly what I was thinking, but `(^|[^\\])\\(?:\\{2})*([5-9]|[1-9]\d+)` performs better

Comment: What number formats should be matched? Is `6.1` valid? What about `6.` or `.1`?

Comment: @ctwheels could you please tell me how to construct this using new RegExp ? It works on regex101 but I have issues using the expression in new RegExp("expression","gi"); I think escaping problems

Comment: @Ziko you could simply use `/expression/gi` rather than `new RegExp("escapedExpression", "gi")`

Comment: @ctwheels Unfortunately I will have to put a dynamic value inside the regex

Comment: @Ziko in that case, you're going to have to escape every backslash and use `new RegExp("escapedRegex", "gi")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS doesn't support lookbehinds (at least not all major browsers do), hence the error. You could try:

```
(?:^|[^\\\n])\\(?:\\{2})*(?![0-4]\b)\d+
```

Or if you care about decimal numbers:

```
(?:^|[^\\\n])\\(?:\\{2})*(?![0-4](?:\.\d*)?\b)\d+(?:\.\d*)?
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/8N2hI5/1)

Note: You don't need `\n` if you don't have multi line text.

**Regex breakdown**:

- `(?:` Beginning of non-capturing group

  - `^` Start of line
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\\\n]` Match nothing but a backslash
- `)` End of non-capturing group
- `\\(?:\\{2})*` Match a backslash following even number of it
- `(?![0-4](?:\.\d*)?\b)` Following number shouldn't be less than 5 (care about decimal numbers)
- `\d+(?:\.\d*)?` Match a number

JS code:

```js
var str = `\\5
\\\\5
\\\\\\5
\\\\\\4
\\4.
\\\\\\6
`;

console.log(
  str.match(/(?:^|[^\\\n])\\(?:\\{2})*(?![0-4](?:\.\d*)?\b)\d+(?:\.\d*)?/gm)
)
```

Comment: Why `\.?` in the negative lookahead?

Comment: `(?![0-4]\.?)\d+\.?\d*` and `(?![0-4](?:\.\d*)?\b)` and `(?![0-4]\b)` don't work the way I think you intend them to and doesn't follow the OP's original intent (based on their original regex). Perhaps you meant `(?!0\d|[0-4](?!\d))`?

Comment: I checked the update. It still fails to exclude `01`

Comment: Including different format of numbers could be a thing that OP should clear. But in this specific case adding optional trailing zeros in lookahead would work: `(?:^|[^\\\n])\\(?:\\{2})*(?!0*[0-4]\b)\d+`

Comment: I've posted comment under question for OP to clarify number formats.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it truly helped with the answer above in the comments. However, is there a good way to detect if a number is bigger than a specific number ? I mean let's say I want the regex to check if the entered number was bigger than 5, is there a good way to do it ? as my regex above is buggy when it comes to number validation

Comment: @Ziko You're welcome. To do numerical comparison in regex, someone may need to write many patterns since there is no comparison but matching. You can't do math with regex. So patterns for matching a range of digits should be written. There is no other way in regular expressions.

Comment: @revo So you suggest that I write many patterns and based on the input number detected I choose the pattern to go with. For example if the input is <5, I construct a RegExp with specific patterns, if >10 I construct with other specific patterns. Right ?

Comment: @Ziko If that is your case and should be done with regex, then unfortunately yes or you can match all digits without any limitations then filter them from returning array by doing some math operations.

Comment: @Ziko Please  check it here http://jsbin.com/pimoletuqo/edit?js,console

Comment: @revo Yeah I did the regex finally and yours helps too to better understand things. However, one last question excuse me, this pattern in my regex [" +groups+"-9]|[1-9]\\d+) causes problems when groups is = 9 ! groups is the number of groups in my input. so If I had 3, it checks if I enter something bigger than 3 but when I have 9 groups, the whole thing gives an error cause I will have something like [9-9] in my pattern. Any hint ?

Comment: @Ziko `[9-9]` is valid. It shouldn't have thrown an error for this. But for `9` you only need second side of alternation: `[1-9]\d+`